# No ability to connect after running mysql_install_db

Tags: mysql

I am initializing a new DB but unable to connect to it -- it says root is not authorized. I was assuming creating a blank/new DB would allow root at localhost to connect. How am I supposed to connect to a newly initialized DB?

```
> service mysql stop
> mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/ebs/db/mysql
> service mysql start

> mysqladmin -u root password ********
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

The "datadir" in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` does point to the correct location, and I don't see any other options that might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple typo to me. The giveaway is the "(using password: NO)" statement in the error message, which means the command you're running did not recognize the password you provided. I assume here that "keufEdBe" is your root password.

Try the following:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p
```

You will then be prompted to enter in the password interactively. If you really want to enter it in on the command line (not recommended, because it will be stored in plain text in your shell history file), you can use this:

```
mysqladmin -u root --password=*******
```

As a rule of thumb, MySQL commands assume that the account you're using is passwordless, unless you explicitly use the -p or --password option. The latter option allows you to specify the password on the command line, but needs the = sign.

I suggest reviewing the built-in help, which will allow you to see all the available options and the syntax differences between using -u vs. --user and -p vs. --password:

```
mysqladmin --help | less
```

I suggest piping to less or more here, since the help screen for this command is quite long. Alternatively you can just run it and scroll up in your terminal program to see the first page of output which contains all the options and their explanations and syntax.

Comment: No, I'm trying to set a password for the first time. There is an empty directory for the Db, I run the db setup, and then try to connect and was refused. I've had no chance to set a password yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is:

```
$ sudo mysql_install_db
$ sudo service mysql start
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
$ mysql -u root -p
```

I think `mysql_install_db` is installing a random password now and has to be reset with `mysql_secure_installation`.

Another option is to run:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst configure
```

Note that the script name could change depending on the version you have installed.

This is tested on Ubuntu, but should work for any debian-based distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database for users in the initial database.

```
service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Try to login to database:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then press ENTER

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> select * from user;
```

Check if you have any users ? If not that's the reason.
You can add root user. Instruction how to you can find in:
http://www.helpfromfriend.com/database/mysql/how-to-recreate-root-account-in-mysql/